# c++ check all array values at once

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

what I want to do is check an array of bools to see if 3 or more of them have been set to true. The only way I can think to do this is using a if statement for each possible combination of which there is lots because there are ten bools. Dose anybody have any suggestions on how best to do this.

Comment: Thanks Guys that helped had to edit the answer a bit because it was inside a while loop but other than that it worked perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The much easier way would be to loop through the array:

```
int numberOfSet = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++ ) {
     if( array[i] ) {
        numberOfSet++;
        //early cut-off so that you don't loop further without need
        // whether you need it depends on how typical it is to have
        // long arrays that have three or more elements set in the beginning
        if( numberOfSet >= 3 ) {
            break;
        }
     }
}

bool result = numberOfSet >= 3;
```

Answer (score 10):

This would be the easiest way:

```
std::count(bool_array, std::end(bool_array), true) >= 3
```

Only problem is it keeps counting even after it has found 3.  If that is a problem, then I would use sharptooth's method.

**side note**

I've decided to fashion an algorithm in the style of [`std::all_of/any_of/none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) for my personal library, perhaps you will find it useful:

```
template<typename InIt, typename P>
bool n_or_more_of(InIt first, InIt last, P p, unsigned n)
{
    while (n && first != last)
    {
        if (p(*first)) --n;
        ++first;
    }
    return n == 0;
}
```

For your purpose, you would use it like this:

```
n_or_more_of(bool_array, std::end(bool_array), [](bool b) { return b; }, 3);
```

Comment: does this mean that I need to use using namespace std and if so can I still use my current using namespace tle.

Comment: @bobthemac: If you're going to use something from the standard library, then you either prefix it with `std::` as I did above.  Or you have a `using` declaration in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are setting an array element into TRUE value, you can increment a global counter. This will be the simplest way. At any point in your code, the global array will tell you the number of TRUE elements in the Array.

Another thing - if you are keeping upto 32 bool values, you can use a single int variable. int is 32 bits (in Win32) and you can store 32 bool.

```
char x = 0; //  00000000 // char is 8 bits

// TO SET TRUE
x = x | (1 << 4); // 00010000
x = x | (1 << 7); // 10010000

// TO SET FALSE
x = x & ~(1 << 4); // 10010000 & 11101111 => 10000000

// TO CHECK True/False
if( x & ~(1 << 4) )
```

Comment: char?  or CHAR?  Either way, it's 8 bits. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505945.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's 8 bits, I was in a Java line, where char is 16 bits, to hold Unicode characters. Thanks for pointing out :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, what you do is loop over it and count the number of trues. But I'm afraid you mean a bitpattern of some kind, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count the number of trues and then do something if the number is 3 or higher:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
  if (arr[i]){
    sum++;
  }
}

if (sum >= 3){
  // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and build a bit-mask representation of the array, then you can compare against up to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long)` in parallel:

```
unsigned long mask = 0;
for (std::vector<bool>::const_iterator it = flags.begin(), end_it = flags.end();
     it != end_it;
     ++it)
{
  if (*it)
    mask |= (1 << (it - flags.begin()));
}

if (mask & (0xaa3)) // or whatever mask you want to check
{
}
```

This assumes that you're looking for *patterns*, not just want to count the number of `true` flags in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array counting the number of bools set to true.

```
/**
 * @param arr The array of booleans to check.
 * @param n How many must be true for this function to return true.
 * @param len The length of arr.
 */
bool hasNTrue(bool *arr, int n, int len) {
    int boolCounter;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (arr[i]) boolCounter++;
    }
    return boolCounter>=n;
}
```

Then call it like so

```
hasNTrue(myArray, 3, myArrayLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the bools as bits in an integer. Then apply one of the [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).